# How to determine if date field is empty or not?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, date-time

I am creating Workflow using SharePoint designer to send the email notification if the date field (revise date) is empty.

I just cant find anything to check if the date field is empty?

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the date column variable with default Empty Date Field value which is '01/01/0001'.

Similar thread: [Check for empty date in SPD Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/check-for-empty-date-in-spd-workflow)

As a workaround you can also create a hidden date field in SharePoint & compare other date column with this hidden empty field.

For more information check: [SharePoint Designer Workflow check if date field is empty](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/check-if-a-date-field-is-null-or-empty-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you use **MS Flow** to implement your design.

In my testing:

1.Create new list named "Flow" and create some columns in this list

[image]

2.On the Flow list, click **Integrate** >> **Power Automate** to create new Flow.

[image]

3.MS Flow:

- a.Add the "**Recurrence**" Trigger:You can customize the trigger period and frequency
- b.Add the "**Get items**" Action
- c.Add the "**Condition**" Action
  [image]
- d.On the "**If yes**" branch. add the "**Send an email(V2)**" Action

4.Save and Test this flow.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment, however I need to do this with SharePoint designer